# Designing an Asp.Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As a novice to this realm, I am planning on building an mvc application. I had originally started a web forms application but decided the scalability and testability will benefit more with an mvc application. I chose to switch with the added benefit of being easier to add more features later on (instead of having code baked into web forms pages).

Now a little about my application, it is an application to stimulate an RPG class builder and moveset. In all simplicity, users can register for a class, and depending on other skills they can register for, they can see a custom move set based on these categories. The way I am envisioning it is I will be able to go back and add more classes and skills later in the database and have users register for this new content immediately once it has been added to the project.

Everything lives in normalized tables, so many joint tables do exist. For each new skill or class I add will mean a handful of tables will be added to the database. This speaks to the way the data will be stored, everything and all information about classes, user data, skills, etc will be stored in the database.

I have designed all the initial database tables I will need to have at the start, and functionality I need (a home page, view skills page, view move sets page, etc.). I am stuck at the next step; where do I go? Should I make my controllers first? Models? Views? Design my page layouts? I am asking for advice from people who have taken a similar organic approach to an mvc project. I am facing analysis paralysis on what to start on, knowing I have a lot of work ahead of me.

Thank you for taking your time to answer.

---

I've taken everyone's advise and am putting together a website to learn MVC: http://learnaspnetmvc.azurewebsites.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The most important advice I can give you: just *start*. A big project can seem overwhelming, especially when you're looking at it like a *big project*. Instead, break it into small achievable tasks. Find something you can do right now, the ever-so-smallest subset of functionality, and do it. Then do the next one. And the next.

That said, I'll tell you my personal process. When I start on a new application or piece of an application, I first like to create my models. That way I can play with the interactions between them, flesh out the relationships, and think about the needs of my application in a somewhat low-pressure, easily disposable way. I also use code-first, whereas you've gone an created your database tables already. Some people prefer to do it that way. Personally, I find starting with my classes and letting those translate into an underlying data store much more organic. In a sense, it relegates the database to almost a non-existent layer. I don't have to think about what datatype things need to be, what should be indexed and what shouldn't, how querying will work, what kind of stored procedures I need, etc. Those questions have their time and place -- the nascent development stage is *not* that time and place. You want to give your brain a place to play with ideas, and classes are a cheap and low-friction medium. If an idea doesn't work out, throw the class away and create a new one.

Once I have my models, I like to hit my controllers next. This lets me start to see my models in action. I can play around with the actual flow of my application and see how my classes actually work. I can then make changes to my models where necessary, add additional functionality, etc. I can also start playing around with view models, and figuring out what data should or should not be passed to the view, how it will need to be displayed (will I need a drop down list for that? etc.), and such. This, then, naturally leads me into my views. Again, I'm testing my thinking. With each new layer, I'm hardening the previous by getting a better and better look at how it's working.

Each stage of this process is very liquid. Once I start working on my controllers, I *will* make changes to my models. Once I hit the views, the controllers will need to be adjusted and perhaps the models as well. You have to give yourself the freedom to screw up. Inevitably, you'll forget something, or design something in a bone-headed way, that you'll only see once you get deeper in. Again, that's the beauty of code-first. Up to this point, I don't even have a database, so any change I make is no big deal. I could completely destroy everything I have and go in a totally different way and I don't have to worry about altering tables, migrating data, etc.

Now, by this point my models are pretty static, and that's when I do my database creation and initial migration. Although, even now, really, only because it's required before I can actually fire this up in a browser to see my views in action. You can always do a migration later, but once you're working with something concrete, the friction starts to increase.

I'll tend to do some tweaking to my controllers and obviously my views, now that I'm seeing them live. Once I'm happy with everything, then I start looking at optimization and refactoring -- How can I make the code more effective? More readable? More efficient? I'll use a tool like [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) to look at my queries, render time, etc., and then make decisions about things like stored procedures and such.

Then, it's just a lot of rinse and repeat. Notice that it's all very piecemeal. I'm not building an application; I'm building a class, and then another class, and then some HTML, etc. You focus on just that next piece, that small chunk you need to move on to the next thing, and it's much less overwhelming. So, just as I began, I'll close the same: just *start*. Writers have a saying that the hardest thing is the first sentence. It's not because the first sentence is really that difficult; it's because once you get that, then you write the second sentence, and the third, and before you know it, you've got pages of writing. The hardest part is in the starting. Everything flows from there.

The other answers here have great advice and important nuggets of information, but I think they do you a disservice at this stage. I'm the first to advocate best practice, proper layering of your applications, etc. But, ultimately, a complete app that follows none of this is more valuable than an incomplete app that incorporates it all. Thankfully, we're working with a malleable medium -- digital text -- and not stone. You can always change things, improve things later. You can go back and separate your app out into the proper layers, create the repositories and services and other abstractions, add in the inversion of control and dependency injection, etc. Those of us who have been doing this awhile do that stuff from the start, but that's because *we've been doing this awhile*. We know how to do that stuff -- a lot of times we already have classes and libraries we drop in for that stuff. For someone just starting off, or for an app in its earliest nascent stage, it can be crippling, though. Instead of just developing your app, you end up spending days or weeks pouring through recommendations, practices, libraries, etc. trying to get a handle on it all, and by the end you have nothing really to show for it. Don't worry about doing things right and do *something*. Then, refactor until it's right.

Comment: Very well stated, I appreciate the thought you put into this Chris! You have very good advice that I will follow to the best of my knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

As a first step in planning a MVC framework application, We should start with a strong Model (typical C# props). This process is going to take most of our time, based on the fact that we need to understand the business first and then the relationships between different workflows and entities. So times business models evolve as time passes. So spend qualitative time on building this layer, but not too much.

Once domain (Business) Models are ready, before we actually start coding for Repository classes, we should define our Repository Contracts which are typically Interfaces. Contracts help all parties(other components) to interact with each other in the exact same way. Then we implement contracts on the Repository component, which is just going to act like PUSH and PULL data from your persistent medium (say database). Remember repository component never going to have any idea on business logic.

Once backend has been established, We can concentrate on my actual business process implementation. We can define one more level of Contract which defines all business operations which are to be done using Model classes. This interface has been implemented by BusinessLogic Component which does the core business activity (specific methods for every business operation). This particular component will use Repository component to delegate business data to persistence medium.

With above step completed, We can easily go and build Controllers. We should be calling business logic component methods in controllers and get work done. Once controllers are done, we can define our views and other UI elements like partial views etc.

[Pictorial representation](http://www.intstrings.com/ramivemula/articles/asp-net-mvc-high-level-architecture/) of the flow is as follows -

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A simple architecture (from high to low level)

1. Presentation Layer
2. Domain Logic Layer
3. Data Access Layer
4. Database

**Presentation** layer is MVC project containing Views, Controllers and optional View-Models.

**Domain Logic** Layer is Class Library project which Presentation layer will access (via DLL or Service reference). This layer contains business logic and rules for the application.

**Data Access** Layer may contain two sub-layers-

1. **Repository**. User repository is best practice for any long term application.
2. **Entity Framework** Model.
   This will communicate with database.

**Database** you already have.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest reading through a book by Scott Millet, called Professional ASP.NET Design Patterns.
ISBN : 0-470292-78-4
Scott walks through what a good ASP.NET site should look like from an architectural standpoint - i.e. DataAccess layers, Business Logic layers, Presentation Layers, Domain events etc.

By following on from industry standards, you will gain a better knowledge of how to correctly put together an MVC web-site.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to make your MVC application around a [ASP.NET Web API](http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/webapi/VG9K040413-What-is-Web-API-and-why-to-use-it-?.html) , since it will help, in case you go for a mobile application later.

Since you are a MVC newbie, you should download some open source projects on MVC shared by seniors in the community. Study two or three projects, and analyze a solution which will the best for you.

A quick googling will get you to some good projects.
e.g.
[Making a simple application](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/486161/Creating-a-simple-application-using-MVC)  , [Prodinner](http://prodinner.codeplex.com/)

After that you should also go through [MSDN tutorial on MVC 5 app with SSO](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) , to enable social logins.