# SQL queries in ASPX File: Is there a better place for them?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

I have a 'best practice' question. I'm making a simple personal blog application and need to store some data. From a separation of concerns standpoint, I feel like the logic that writes to the database should be stored somewhere other than the ASPX file. Is it common practice to have database logic in the ASPX file, or is there a better way?

Here's an example of what I'm writing inside the ASPX file:

```
private void updateUserInformation()
    {
        string connection_string = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PersonalBlog.mdb";
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connection_string))
        {
            string sqlString = "UPDATE USERS SET [FIRST]=?,[LAST]=?,[EMAIL]=?,[MODIFIED_AT]=? WHERE [ID]=?";
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlString, connection))
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("FIRST", this.txtFirst.Text.Trim());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("LAST", this.txtLast.Text.Trim());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("EMAIL", this.txtEmail.Text.Trim());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("MODIFIED_AT", DateTime.Now.ToString());
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID", Int32.Parse(this.txtUserID.Text.Trim()));
                connection.Open();
                int rowsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                if (rowsAffected > 0)
                {
                    Response.Write("<script>alert('Row has been updated!');</script>");
                    Response.Redirect("CreateAccount.aspx");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that you should create a data access layer. In that layer you would store cs files that contain methods for your queries. That way if you need to access this query from another part of your project or you add the dlls to another project it is still reusable.

Comment: See this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577221/designing-an-asp-net-mvc-application/23577283#23577283

Comment: If you know what "separation of concerns" means, then the answer is not surprising. Database logic (or any non-presentation logic) should not be in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best practice dictates that Data Access belongs in a separate layer (or file) of your application. I will assume that most of your operations are CRUD (Create/Read/Update/Delete) and therefore will provide a simple solution for you:

## Move Connection Strings To Configuration File

Having the connection string directly in the code is bad, as when you move from development to production, you can't change it. Instead, place them in a separate configuration file so that you can change it, without re-compiling the code

In your Web.config, add the following section:

```
<configuration>
   <connectionStrings>
      <add name="DBConnectionString"
           connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\PersonalBlog.mdb"/>
   </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

## Create a class for each table

Your application looks like the classes represent the table structures. Instead of writing raw SQL, create a class to store the data like this:

```
public class User
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string First { get; set }
   public string Last { get; set ; }
   public string Email { get; set; }
   public DateTime ModifiedAt { get; set; }
}
```

## Centralise Data Access Code

Next is to create a repository to house your data access logic. Its common to use an ORM framework to write the Connection/Command code for you, since this saves you having to write T-SQL at all. Since this application looks straightforward, I won't go the full hog and separate the concerns completely, but just give a tidier example.

This example uses Entity Framework:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
   // name="DBConnectionString" is the <connectionString -> name> from Web.config
   public DatabaseContext() : base("name=DBConnectionString") { }

   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

   protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
   {
       // Define mappings
       modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("USERS");
       modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasKey(x=>x.Id);
   }
}
```

And from there, you can update your ASPX as follows:

```
private void updateUserInformation()
{
    int rowsAffected = 0;

    using(var dbContext = new DatabaseContext())
    {
        int userId = int.Parse(this.txtUserID.Text);

        // Load record to be updated - changes are tracked internally
        User userToUpdate = dbContext.Users.Find(userId);

        userToUpdate.First = this.txtFirst.Text.Trim();
        userToUpdate.Last = this.txtLast.Text.Trim();
        userToUpdate.Email = this.txtEmail.Text.Trim();
        userToUpdate.ModifiedAt = DateTime.Now;

        // Commit changes to DB
        rowsAffected = dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    if (rowsAffected > 0)
    {
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Row has been updated!');</script>");
        Response.Redirect("CreateAccount.aspx");
    }
}
```